# how to enhance the features of builtin functions in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am new to python programming,
i like to know how can i enhance the features of builtin functions([Monkeypatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch))

for example

i know [sum()](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/functions.html#sum) built in function allowed only on number items

```
>>> sum([4,5,6,7]) #22
```

i would like to make sum function to be allow list of items as strings as shown below

for example

```
>>> sum(['s','t','a','c','k']) # 'stack'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your question how to do monkey patching, or how to write that particular function?

Comment: You should accept abarnert's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17098594/846892), it is surely better than mine.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: No, abarnerts' answer is flawed.

Comment: @nmclean's answer is the simplest and correct.

Comment: @EthanFurman: It's only flawed because you're misreading it. That may be my fault for not being clear enough; I've rewritten it to explain that better.

Comment: @abarnert: Thanks for fixing it so I'm not misreading anymore. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not monkey patching exactly, just re-defined `sum` to make it work for strings as well.

```
>>> import __builtin__
def sum(seq, start = 0):
    if all(isinstance(x,str) for x in seq):
        return "".join(seq)
    else:
        return __builtin__.sum(seq, start)
...     
>>> sum([4,5,6,7])
22
>>> sum(['s','t','a','c','k'])
'stack'
```

Answer (score 12):

You can't really "monkeypatch" a function the way you can a class, object, module, etc.

Those other things all ultimately come down to a collection of attributes, so replacing one attribute with a different one, or adding a new one, is both easy and useful. Functions, on the other hand, are basically atomic things.*

You can, of course, monkeypatch the builtins module by replacing the `sum` function. But I don't think that's what you were asking. (If you were, see below.)

Anyway, you can't patch `sum`, but you can write a new function, with the same name if you want, (possibly with a wrapper around the original function—which, you'll notice, is exactly what decorators do).

---

But there is really no way to use `sum(['s','t','a','c','k'])` to do what you want, because `sum` by default starts off with 0 and adds things to it. And you can't add a string to 0.**

Of course you can always pass an explicit `start` instead of using the default, but you'd have to change your calling code to send the appropriate `start`. In some cases (e.g., where you're sending a literal list display) it's pretty obvious; in other cases (e.g., in a generic function) it may not be. That still won't work here, because `sum(['s','t','a','c','k'], '')` will just raise a `TypeError` (try it and read the error to see why), but it will work in other cases.

But there is no way to avoid having to know an appropriate starting value with `sum`, because that's how `sum` works.

If you think about it, `sum` is conceptually equivalent to:

```
def sum(iterable, start=0):
    reduce(operator.add, iterable, start)
```

The only real problem here is that `start`, right? `reduce` allows you to leave off the start value, and it will start with the first value in the iterable:

```
>>> reduce(operator.add, ['s', 't', 'a', 'c', 'k'])
'stack'
```

That's something `sum` can't do. But, if you really want to, you can redefine `sum` so it *can*:

```
>>> def sum(iterable):
...     return reduce(operator.add, iterable)
```

… or:

```
>>> sentinel = object()
>>> def sum(iterable, start=sentinel):
...     if start is sentinel:
...         return reduce(operator.add, iterable)
...     else:
...         return reduce(operator.add, iterable, start)
```

But note that this `sum` will be much slower on integers than the original one, and it will raise a `TypeError` instead of returning `0` on an empty sequence, and so on.

---

If you really do want to monkeypatch the builtins (as opposed to just defining a new function with a new name, or a new function with the same name in your module's `globals()` that shadows the builtin), here's an example that works for Python 3.1+, as long as your modules are using normal globals dictionaries (which they will be unless you're running in an embedded interpreter or an `exec` call or similar):

```
import builtins
builtins.sum = _new_sum
```

In other words, same as monkeypatching any other module.

In 2.x, the module is called `__builtin__`. And the rules for how it's accessed through globals changed somewhere around 2.3 and again in 3.0. See [`builtins`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html)/[`__builtin__`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/__builtin__.html) for details.

---

* Of course that isn't *quite* true. A function has a name, a list of closure cells, a doc string, etc. on top of its code object. And even the code object is a sequence of bytecodes, and you can use `bytecodehacks` or hard-coded hackery on that. Except that `sum` is actually a builtin-function, not a function, so it doesn't even have code accessible from Python… Anyway, it's close enough for most purposes to say that functions are atomic things.

** Sure, you *could* convert the string to some subclass that knows how to add itself to integers (by ignoring them), but really, you don't want to.

Comment: Deserves +10 for the footnotes alone.

Comment: As always, a great answer. :)

Comment: `0` is a problem?  It's a default argument -- specify something else that's appropriate for whatever you're summing and you'll be fine (except for `str`, of course, since that is special-cased to fail).

Comment: @EthanFurman: `0` is a problem because the OP specifically wants to be able to call `sum` without having to specify a start value, and you can't do that with `sum`. Which means either he has to use a function that works the way he wants like `reduce` or `''.join`, or he has to change what he wants. The former is at least as reasonable as the latter (It handles questions like "How do you write a generic function that uses `sum` appropriately on any type?" "You don't; you use `reduce`".). But you're right to point out that the latter is also perfectly reasonable for the OP's case.

Comment: I didn't see anything in the OP's posts to suggest he didn't *want* to specify a start value; rather I suspect he didn't know he could.

Comment: @EthanFurman: I was assuming he'd done a `help(sum)` or equivalent before asking this question (probably because I implicitly assumed anyone who doesn't know how to find the docs wouldn't be asking about monkeypatching). But I could well be wrong.

Comment: I could also be wrong; you have some good stuff in your answer -- my only problem with it is the paragraph that explains why `sum` doesn't work for strings.  `sum` doesn't work for strings because they are special-cased to fail; it has nothing to do with the default start value of zero.  I would happily change my down-vote to an up-vote if you fixed that.

Comment: @EthanFurman: That's the reason `sum` doesn't work _the way he wants to call it_ with strings. I'll gladly edit the answer to make the distinction clearer.

Comment: Nice revision.  Good answer!

Answer (score 3):

To do what you want, you should use [`str.join`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
"".join(['s','t','a','c','k'])
```

Monkey patching is possible, but frowned upon, in Python, especially for trivial things like this. It will make you code harder to read, because standard library functions will do unexpected things.

But, if you really want to, you can just redefine the function. Python won't stop you:

```
def sum(l):
    return "".join(l)
```

Python will let you do whatever you want to existing modules:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open("somefile", "w")
```

But again, you shouldn't.

Comment: Re-defining the `sum` function is not monkey patching I guess, your new `sum` function won't work for numbers.

Comment: @user1559873 I agree. You shouldn't do monkey patching.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary How is this not monkey patching? It changes the standard library at runtime. The question was how to do monkey patching, not how to write that specific function. The one I gave was an example of how to monkey patch `sum` to join a list of strings.

Comment: @BrendanLong: Hiding `builtins.sum` with `globals().sum` isn't really monkeypatching anything, unless defining a local variable with the same name as a global or nonlocal counts as monkeypatching…

Comment: @Brendan after monkey patch it should perform its actual functionality as well  as Ashwini said It should work for both strings and numbers.

Comment: I think the point of this answer is that if you're writing Python, write your code like Python is supposed to be. Don't go messing with the language to fit your paradigm; write code Pythonically!

Comment: @user1559873: So you want it to work for strings and numbers… but not for other addable types?

Comment: @user1559873: About a quarter of the total documentation for [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) is about how you shouldn't really use it for strings: "The preferred, fast way to concatenate a sequence of strings is by calling `''.join(sequence)`." So, once you've decided that you really want `sum` to work on strings without passing `start=''`, you're probably already beyond the bounds of a right approach.

Answer (score 3):

`sum` already works with anything that defines an `__add__` function. The second parameter is the starting point, which defaults to 0, but you can replace it with the "nothing" version of whatever you're summing. For example, adding together a list of lists, starting with an empty list:

```
sum([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [])
```

returns:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

So normally, this would actually work:

```
sum(['s','t','a','c','k'], '')
```

but this raises an exception which specifically tells you to use `join` for strings. Probably because it performs better.

Answer (score 1):

Easier to ask forgiveness than permission:

```
import __builtin__
def sum(seq, start = 0):
    try:
        return "".join(seq)
    except TypeError:
        return __builtin__.sum(seq, start)
...     
>>> sum([4,5,6,7])
22
>>> sum(['s','t','a','c','k'])
'stack'
```

Please forgive me if this looks like I just copied most of someone else's answer. :)

**But seriously,** you should just use `''.join()` instead as @nmclean has explained in an under appreciated answer.